# How to pause and resume kafka consumer thread safely using spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

In spring doc, it says:

> Previously, you could pause a consumer within a ConsumerAwareMessageListener 
>   and resume it by listening for a ListenerContainerIdleEvent, which provides 
>   access to the Consumer object. While you could pause a consumer in an idle 
>   container by using an event listener, in some cases, this was not thread- 
>   safe, since there is no guarantee that the event listener is invoked on the 
>   consumer thread. To safely pause and resume consumers, you should use the 
>   pause and resume methods on the listener containers.

Since I use a version that don't support pause or resume container, I have to use ListenerContainerIdleEvent to resume the consumer.I want to know what it means:

> While you could pause a consumer in an idle 
>   container by using an event listener, in some cases, this was not thread- 
>   safe, since there is no guarantee that the event listener is invoked on the 
>   consumer thread.

Does it mean that I can thread safely pause an consumer in a ConsumerAwareMessageListener and resume it in ListenerContainerIdleEvent, but pausing consumer in an ListenerContainerIdleEvent has risks?

Answer (score 0):

There are no risks with the default application event multicaster because it calls the event listener on the calling thread (the consumer thread).

The issue is when you use a custom multicaster with a task executor.